# Turning divs into functions click, mouseover, and mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

this might be a very stupid question. I want to access different divs and interact with one another without using buttons functions, so I am trying to turn a normal div into a function when it hovers and then when out it does another animation and when clicked it should do something else.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lshp4ofw/67/

```
var BaseGraph = document.getElementById("BaseGraphic");
var BaseGraph = BaseGraphAct;
var BaseGraphAct = function(){
if(BaseGraph){
BaseGraph.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
event.InteraBase = document.getElementById("InteractionBase");
InteraBase.classList.remove("dead");
});}
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Say I want to make DivA blue when DivB is mouseover, and on-click make DivA yellow, then on mouseout making DivA Light Blue.  Should I just not put them all into a function? and make each of them EventListerners separate?

Comment: you have put the `addEventListener` inside another function, which I can't see being called anywhere. move that of the function and it should work fine. Also, you're declaring `BaseGraph` again, with a value `BaseGraphAct` which doesn't exist yet, so `BaseGraph` becomes undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how you can change state of div with class 'dead' from another div:

```
var BaseGraph = document.getElementById("BaseGraphic");
var IB = document.getElementById("InteractionBase");

BaseGraph.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {    
    IB.classList.remove('dead');
});
BaseGraph.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
    IB.classList.add('dead');
});
```